# Структура БЭМ документа

Tags: бэм

Какая структура правильнее по БЭМ и почему?

1.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-entry">
      <div class="post__title"></div>
      <div class="post__text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post__entry">
      <div class="post__title"></div>
      <div class="post__text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Так у вас идентичные блоки...
Касательно именований. По сути, нет строгих правил, которых нужно придерживаться, но есть основы, которые надо понимать и придерживаться (такие как блоки и эл-ты, к примеру). Вот, к примеру ваш блок.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-entry">
      <div class="post__title"></div>
      <div class="post__text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

С точки зрения БЭМ, практически любые именования допустимы и вы ничего не нарушаете. Но с точки зрения восприятия, легче воспринимать блок когда он именован так, чтобы сделать заметным какой части он пренадлежит. Это в случае, если эл-ты блока могут использоваться только в самом блоке. Например, так:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post__entry">
        <div class="post__title"></div> \\ или так: post__entry-title
        <div class="post__text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если же эл-ты блока могут быть использованы и вне блока, то нет смысла давать им именования, условно, вида `post__title`.
Но, не стоит забывать о правилах именований, которые не допускают выражение, как `post__entry__title` -это уже было бы ошибкой, посколько двумя подчеркиваниями разделяются только имя блока от имени эл-та. Через одно подчеркивание - это уже модификаторы и не разрешается использования в имени более 1, надо больше - можно добавить ещё одно имя (класс).

`post__entry-title_visible_hidden`

`post` - имя блока

`entry-title` - имя эл-та

`visible` - модификатор

`hidden` - значение модификатора (значение не обязательно записывать, можно только модификатор оставлять)

При этом, важно, что использование имён только с модификаторами запрещено. Обязательно сперва должно идти имя эл-та и только после +модификатор.

`<div class="post__entry-title_visible_hidden"></div>` - так нельзя

`<div class="post__entry-title post__entry-title_visible_hidden"></div>` - так можно (нужно)